# How to add custom text in wordpress logs

Tags: plugin-development

I am developing a custom code in wordpress and in order to debug that I need to know if I can add custom text in wpdebug log Please help me if i can do it

Comment: try with this : `trigger_error("message 1", E_USER_NOTICE );`

Comment: @mmm you should leave that as an answer, with an introduction to `trigger_error` and a link to the PHP docs I'd +1

Comment: just to note there is also `error_prepend_string` PHP setting, you could set this to identify a debug session...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello Please add following code snippet in your theme's functions.php file

```
if (!function_exists('write_log')) {
    function write_log ( $log )  {
        if ( true === WP_DEBUG ) {
            if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
                error_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
            } else {
                error_log( $log );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can add custom log as and when you wish by using following output

```
write_log('THIS IS THE START OF MY CUSTOM DEBUG');

write_log($your_variable);
```

Do let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 5):

WordPress doesn't have a debug log, instead, use the standard PHP log and associated functions, e.g.:

```
error_log( 'information goes here' );
```

`trigger_error` can generate notices/warnings, but be careful of using `trigger_error` as it can stop execution and trigger a fatal error

Comment: `trigger_error ()` can generate warnings/notices, not just fatals. It can be more appropriate in many cases since what happens is customizable downstream.